# Spread sheet column values not displaying correctly in console window after Z

Tags: c#, excel, ascii

The code below takes in data from an Excel spread sheet validates the data from a set of pre defined rules and writes out any errors to the console.

This works up to a point. The data returns as expected up to column Z. If any errors are returned passed Z. AB, AC, AD, etc. Then return values start messing up an I get values returned like ], ~, ?. I believe this issue is down to ASCII as I am starting from dec 65 (A). I guess I need to write some kind of Method that can cope with this but do not know where to start. Any help is much appreciated.

```
namespace WorksheetValidator
{
    public class XcelReader
    {
        private readonly List<List<IRule>> m_Rules;

        public XcelReader(List<List<IRule>> rules)
        {
            m_Rules = rules;
        }

        public void ValidateWorksheet(string fileName)
        {
            bool allRulesPassed = true;

            WorkbookProvider workbookProvider = new WorkbookProvider();

            IWorkbook workbook;

            using (FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(fileName))
                workbook = workbookProvider.GetWorkbook(fileStream, SpreadsheetType.Xlsx);

            for (int rowCounter = 1; rowCounter < workbook.Worksheets[1].Rows.Count; rowCounter++)
            {
                IRow row = workbook.Worksheets[1].Rows[rowCounter];

                for (int columnCounter = 0; columnCounter < row.Cells.Count; columnCounter++)
                {
                    List<string> failedRules = ColumnValueIsValid(row.Cells[columnCounter].Value, m_Rules[columnCounter]);

                    failedRules.ForEach(failedRule =>
                    {
                        allRulesPassed = false;
                        Console.WriteLine("\n[{0}:{1}] Failed: {2}", rowCounter + 1, (char)(columnCounter + 65), failedRule);
                    });
                }
            }

            if(allRulesPassed)
                Console.WriteLine("\n\n\nWOOHOO! worksheet is hunky dory");
        }

        private List<string> ColumnValueIsValid(string value, List<IRule> rules)
        {
            List<string> failedRules = new List<string>();

             rules.ForEach(rule =>
             {
                 if(!rule.IsValid(value))
                     failedRules.Add(rule.GetReasonForFailure(value));
             });

            return failedRules;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
(char)(columnCounter + 65)
```

With a function that converts 0 to "A", 1 to "B"..... 26 to "AA", 27 to "AB", etc.